# How to make a contingency table where one variable is categorized based on given breaks

Tags: r

Given a data.frame like the following

```
ID  Card.Type  Mount
001   Basic    500
002   Basic    400
003   Basic    700
004   Basic    1000
005   Silver   1200
006   Silver   1300
007   Basic    800
008   Silver   1400
009   Gold     2500
0010  Gold     5000
0012  Gold     7000
0013  Gold     15000
```

I want to create a contingency table where the values of `Mount` are categorized into intervals based on a vector `B=c(0,100,500,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000)`. The result would be a table like this:

```
Card.Type   0-100 101-500 501-1000 1001-2000 2001-3000 3001-4000 4001-5000 >5000
Basic         0       2      2         0          0        0         0       0
Silver        0       0      0         3          0        0         0       0
Gold          0       0      0         0          1        0         1       2
```

I was trying a `data.table` solution but was not able to get this result. How can I make this table or is possible to add extra option when calling `table()` function to get this result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="ID  Card.Type  Mount
001   Basic    500
002   Basic    400
003   Basic    700
004   Basic    1000
005   Silver   1200
006   Silver   1300
007   Basic    800
008   Silver   1400
009   Gold     2500
0010  Gold     5000
0012  Gold     7000
0013  Gold     15000",header=TRUE)

DF$inter <- cut(DF$Mount,c(-1,100,500,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,Inf))
table(DF[,c(2,4)])

# Card.Type (-1,100] (100,500] (500,1e+03] (1e+03,2e+03] (2e+03,3e+03] (3e+03,4e+03] (4e+03,5e+03] (5e+03,Inf]
# Basic        0         2           3             0             0             0             0           0
# Gold         0         0           0             0             1             0             1           2
# Silver       0         0           0             3             0             0             0           0
```